# Cannot import any firebase related classes

Tags: android, firebase

I had to setup my android project new. The old version is not working anymore (IDE is not recognizing or whatever).
So I decided to copy all classes in a new project.
But I cannot use any import such as

```
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
```

I alway get 'Cannot resolve symbol firebase' message.

Here my Gradle app file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            applicationId "tgoa.com.moerder"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.8'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In the gradle build I have included

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate Cache and Restart` option in your Android Studio. This might work. And also after restart `Clean and Build` your project.

Answer (score 1):

I would check that you have Google Play Services and the Google Repository installed in Android Studio. You can check that via the SDK manager.

Also, make sure that the file **google-services.json** is inside your "app" directory.

Comment: thats both positive... I just updated a few hours ago and json file is also there

I also cannot import 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;'

Comment: What version of AS do you have?

Comment: I have Version 2.2.2

Comment: Have you tried going to Tools, then Firebase, and then setting it up from there?

Comment: Yes. It says it is 'connected' and 'Dependencies set up correctly'.

Comment: I had this problem... If I remember correctly, I had  to clean and rebuild the project and restart AS. If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas :(

Answer (score 1):

Android studio 2.2 directly provide plugin for firebase.

Have you tried using **Tools --> Firebase** Then give you step by step Guide.

I think in your case problem in  **buildToolsVersion**

`buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

Replace with

```
buildToolsVersion "24.2.1"
```

**Note :-** **open your sdk folder --> open build-tools --> set available version  version in your folder**

In your case set available 24 version in gradle.

Comment: Hi, the json-file is in the app folder. Build is working, but I cannot use suggested imports. I alway get 'Cannot resolve symbol firebase' message. Same for 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;'

Comment: I get an error when I put buildToolsVersion to 24.2.1
"All packages are not available for download!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128508/discussion-between-arpit-patel-and-jendrik).

Comment: use buildToolsVersion "24.0.0" and try this

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add rules to your root-level build.gradle file, to include the google-services plugin:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your project build.gradle, add `mavenLocal()` to the repository

Answer (score -1):

Go to File in Android studio Top left corner and click "invalidate and restart"